# rabbitmq how to set peer certificate verification for some specific mqtts ports only?

Tags: security, ssl, rabbitmq, tls1.2

Here I have put fail_if_no_peer_cert as true to enable the client certificate verification.
I have 2 MQTTS ports which are 1884 and 2500. I just want to enable this peer verification only to the port 1884. Port 2500 I want to use as one way SSL with fail_if_no_peer_cert as false.

Is there a way to do this in rabbitmq.config?

following is my rabbitmq.config file

```
[
    { 
    rabbit, [
            { loopback_users, [ ] },
            { tcp_listeners, [ 5672 ] },
            { ssl_listeners, [  ] },
            { ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/home/akila/test/tls-gen/basic/result/ca_certificate.pem"},
            {certfile,"/home/akila/test/tls-gen/basic/result/server_certificate.pem"},
            {keyfile,"/home/akila/test/tls-gen/basic/result/server_key.pem"},
            {versions, ['tlsv1.2', 'tlsv1.1']},
            {verify,verify_peer},
            {fail_if_no_peer_cert,true}]},
            { hipe_compile, false },
            { auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_internal,rabbit_auth_backend_http]}
    ]
    },
    {rabbitmq_management, [ 
            { listener, [
                    { port, 15672 },
                    { ssl, false }
            ] } ] 
    },
    {rabbitmq_mqtt, [
            {ssl_listeners,    [1884,2500]},
            {tcp_listeners,    [1883]}
            ]}
```

].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to specify per-port TLS settings for the MQTT plugin at this time -

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/a7PKyo3tRHc/s-KiaBgSBAAJ